# How do I spell out the page numbers in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

In MS-Word (any version, but I"m using 2010) is there a way to set the page numbers as using alpha-values instead of numeric values?

For example, I would like the page numbers in my header to display as, "Page One", "Page Two", etc.

I found that Chapters can be set in a similar fashion, "Section One", "Section 2", but not pages.

I suppose that I could create a bunch of sections in my document, but that would be hard to manage and would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done using Word [field switches](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/format-field-switch-HP005186222.aspx).

Start by adding numeric page numbers to your document header in the usual way. With the header in edit mode click the page number digit to select it (it will be highlighted gray).  Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F9</kbd> to toggle on the field codes.  Click just inside the closing bracket and enter the switches as shown below.
`{PAGE \*CardText \*Caps}`
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F9</kbd> again to toggle off the field codes.